# Is this the most optimal way to write this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Is there a better way to write this Ruby code? Please help to refactor.

```
def get_code(val)
    case val
    when 0..20 then 'E2'
    when 20..32 then 'E1'
    when 33..40 then 'D'
    when 41..50 then 'C2'
    when 51..60 then 'C1'
    when 61..70 then 'B2'
    when 71..80 then 'B1'
    when 81..90 then 'A2'
    when 91..100 then 'A1'
    else 'A0'
    end
 end
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Seems perfectly understandable to me.

Comment: Too lengthy? Just wanted to see if any refactoring is possible.

Comment: the 20..32 and 33..40 part looks irregular. Is that a typo?

Comment: Shorter does not mean better nor does it mean concise.

Comment: `20..32` will never match `20`, it should be `21..32`.

Comment: Code reviews should be on [Code Review.SE](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.Com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_code(val)
    if [31, 32].include?(val) then 'E1'
    else ['E2', 'E2', 'E1', 'D', 'C2', 'C1', 'B2', 'B1', 'A2', 'A1'][(val-1)/10] || 'A0'
    end
end
```

I am not sure about how you are dealing with 0, negatives. It looks like a grading system. If there is a mistake to my code, I think you will be able to fix it.

**Update**
Another version:

```
def get_code(val)
    val += 1 if 0 == val
    val -= 2 if [31, 32].include?(val)
    ['E2', 'E2', 'E1', 'D', 'C2', 'C1', 'B2', 'B1', 'A2', 'A1'][(val-1)/10] || 'A0'
end
```

Comment: The clever answer. Please don't change your perfectly clear code to this. Think of the children.

Comment: What does the ? after the (val) do?

Comment: @Vijay typo. I first tried ternary operator, and changed my mind.

Comment: @Vijay Dev, It is a magick. Ruby magick. It disappears after midnight :)

Comment: @fl00r @Martinho @Vijay This situation reminds me of Zeller's congruence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence. Forcing a mildly irregular list to follow from a formula.

Comment: Accepting this one for the geekiness :P @fl00r: I liked your answer too. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is quite good.
For fun you can use hash instead of `case`.

```
def get_code(val)
  my_hash = { 0..20 => 'E2',
    20..32 => 'E1',
    33..40 => 'D',
    41..50 => 'C2',
    51..60 => 'C1',
    61..70 => 'B2',
    71..80 => 'B1',
    81..90 => 'A2',
    91..100 => 'A1' }
  my_hash.select{ |k, v| k === val }.first[1] rescue 'A0'
end
```

Or to make it more inline :)

```
def get_code(val)
  { 0..20 => 'E2', 20..32 => 'E1', 33..40 => 'D', 41..50 => 'C2', 51..60 => 'C1', 61..70 => 'B2', 71..80 => 'B1', 81..90 => 'A2', 91..100 => 'A1' }.select{ |k, v| k === val }.first[1] rescue 'A0'
end
```

and, as @Geo noticed, you should extract your hash out of method.

Comment: But you would probably place the hash outside of the function, and add it to a class,right? Because if you would call this multiple times, you'd be creating a lot of Hashes only to access their keys once.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only instance of this pattern, then it's not worth shortening; it's perfectly clear as it is, and not very noisy.

Answer (score 1):

Not a refactoring, just a shorter way to write it:

```
def get_code(val)
    case val
    when 0..20
      'E2'
    when 20..32
      'E1'
    when 33..40
      'D'
    when 41..50
      'C2'
    # etc.
    else
      'A0'
    end
 end
```

Or you could substitute the *then*'s with semi-colons:

```
case val
  when  0..20; 'E2'
  when 20..32; 'E1'
  #etc
  else 'A0'
end
```